Movie with a scene of a reused condom with chewing gum sticking on it
The general visual impression of the Movie reminded me of the 80s, one scene of it was like this:
A young man had sexual intercourse with a woman, the woman left but the used condom stayed inside the dustbin. The young man seemed to have a voluminous hairstyle reminding a Jew-fro. 
Another woman enters the location, it is his girlfriend who demands to have intercourse. The man has no contraceptives left and so he decides to reuse the one from the dustbin. But he does not notice the chewing gum stuck to it while approaching his girlfriend. The girlfriend notices it, deduces what scenario might lead to the sticking chewing gum and leaves in anger. 

Ugh, brings a new meaning to dirty sex. shudder

Sounds familiar. And Trish, IIRC, the movie was actually more heartfelt than crass. I just can't place it. :(

Took a while, but I finally recalled where I saw a similar scene: Romantic drama The Rachel Papers from 1989 with Dexter Fletcher and  Ione Skye.

Charles is in control of his life; he is about to finish 6th form college and start at Oxford. He is 19 and wants an 'older' woman before he turns 20. Enter the beautiful Rachel, and Charles puts his 'master-of-seduction' routines into top gear.

At one point Charles cheats on Rachel with a woman named Gloria. Rachel comes in soon after that and suspects he slept with another woman, and her suspicion is confirmed when he's trying to put on a used condom to mask the fact that he used the last one. I'm almost certain that he fishes it out of the trash can with Gloria's gum still stuck to it.
It was based on a 1973 novel. Here's the trailer:



